# Lock the method/code for different different user which is using different browser at same time to acces this method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0

I am using mvc with Entity framework.

I have one method which is called on button click. method used to get the some value from db. And I am doing some calculation and subtracting the value based on my requirement. At the end I am updating this entity with latest changes.

If I don't have enough value in db for subtraction I want to show the error message to user "Enough value in db". its working fine for single user.

But if that method is called by different user at same time from different-different browser, then its not working.

I have tried with lock the Object or async await but not able to handle this situation. lock is not working on event which is fired by different-2 browser at same time.

Code:

```
 public async Task SaveContainerRoutes(List<ContainerRouteVM> lstCRoute, int cid)
    {
       //my code
    }
```

Lock code:

```
 public ActionResult SaveContainerRoutes(List<ContainerRouteVM> lstCRoute, int cid)
    {
        try
        {
            ContainerRouteBL bl = new ContainerRouteBL();
            lock (bl)
            {
                string note = bl.SaveContainerRoutes(lstCRoute, cid);        
            }    
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, message = ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where's the `lock` in your code?

Comment: What is not working? Is there an error or a descrepancy between expected and actual output? If so, what is the discrepancy?

Comment: You need a different mechanism for this. When you discover, *server-side* that you don't have all the requirements you need to return a response to the *client* requesting more data. At this time the server-side code is done, no longer executing. If you want to prevent another user from accessing the same code at the same time you will have a brittle system, what if the first user simply leaves his browser opens but never responds? In any case, the server-side code has finished executing, any lock you took will be released.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare this line in class level

```
private static Object thisLock = new Object();
```

use thislock in method

```
public async Task SaveContainerRoutes(List<ContainerRouteVM> lstCRoute, int cid)
{
    lock(thisLock)
    {
         //place use code
    }
}
```